# Hazelcast logging doesn't work

Tags: tomcat7, hazelcast

We followed all the posts and documentation out there but can't get any `DEBUG` statements generated by Hazelcast.
Hazelcast v.3.4.1  Tomcat 7 application server. Slf4j v.1.7.5
Hazelcast config:

```
<properties>
    <property name="hazelcast.logging.type">slf4j</property>    
  </properties>
```

Logback.xml
EDIT: Here is a full logback.xml

```
<configuration scan="true">
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{0} - [%X{sessionID}] -   [%X{loginID}] -  %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${catalina.base}/logs/app.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${catalina.base}/logs/app.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>2</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger -  [%X{sessionID}] - [%X{loginID}] - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender> 

<logger name="org.mybatis" level="debug" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</logger>  

<logger name="com.hazelcast" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</logger>

<root level="warn">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>
```

Seems like something else is needed.  No hazelcast logging is visible.
I would appreciate some help.

Comment: Do you get ANY logging from Hazelcast?

Comment: I believe there are a couple of INFO messages in catalina about the nodes going down..  But that's about it.

Comment: Can you paste your complete logback.xml ?

Comment: Do you have any proof whatsoever that your logging config XML is being honored? By anything, not just Hazelcast?

Comment: Yes, it's honored as other loggers do show up...

Comment: is it not a default logback,xml loaded from a jar, do you have classpath with correct order? is it a folder with logback.xml before jars ?

Answer (score 1):

Do you see somethng like this in the logging?

```
INFO: [192.168.122.1]:5701 [dev] [3.5.1] 


Members [1] {
    Member [192.168.122.1]:5701 this
}
```

Because this is a clear indication that the Hazelcast logging is working correctly. If you don't see this, then there really is a logging problem, otherwise there probably is some kind of log level problem.

Comment: Yes, i see this.  But never anything else, nothing in Debug or Finest.

Comment: Can you update your original post by including your logging configuration like Dinish suggested. It is very likely that there is some kind of problem there.